# How to handle a new window pop up with selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently automating an application using selenium ,and when a button is clicked a new pop up window appears.I have to switch to that window and do certain operation such as searching of record.

Note **The Parent window and child window have same title .**

Comment: You can switch to the new window by index

Comment: Thanks Madhan, i am new in selenium could you please give me one example how we can use index in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for which you have to provide the index of the window you want to switch

```
switchToWindowByIndex(1);

public void switchToWindowByIndex(int wndIndex) {
    Set<String> handles = Driver.getWindowHandles();
    if (handles.size() > wndIndex) {
        String handle = handles.toArray()[wndIndex].toString();
        Driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("There are only [" + handles.size() + "] windows present at the moment.Requested window is [" + wndIndex + "] which is out of range");
    }
}
```